# Passing multiple parameters with one radio_button_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have:

```
radio_button_tag :item, value
```

However I want a radio_button_tag that I passes multiple parameters on submit.

Something like this:

```
radio_button_tag "item", "value", "item2", "value2"
```

Comment: So, when selecting the "item" radio button, you want "item2" to be set to something specific? If I understand you correctly, you can do this in the controller

Comment: Yes this is what I want to do and thanks I realise how this can be done through the controller! Seems so obvious now but I'm new to rails :) I tried to select your reply as an answer but for some reason I couldn't...

Comment: @Riina U can only select answer as answer, but not comment. Why do u want to pass multiple values via radio button? What's the use case?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `select` not a radio button. The whole point of radio buttons is that only a single button per input (group) can be active at the same time.

[Radio buttons on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/radio)

```
<label>Whats for breakfast?</label>
<select name="select" multiple="true">
  <option value="value1">Eggs</option> 
  <option value="value2" selected>Bacon</option>
  <option value="value3">Oatmeal</option>
</select>
```

Rails has several helpers for creating selects and option tags. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer: [Rails radio_button_tag how to send multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35861158/rails-radio-button-tag-how-to-send-multiple-parameters)

In essence, pass back and forth an array with the params you need, and use the `.split[]` method to retrieve them in the controller.