# Rails radio_button_tag how to send multiple parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, radio-button, radio-group

I'm trying to figure out, if it possible to send multiple parameters with radio button.

First parameter will be `time` and second `provider_id`. I'm using each method for providers, and trying to have option to select only one time and only from one provider.

My view `form_tag`:

```
<%= form_tag(provider_order_create_path)  %>

  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

   <% @group.provider.each do |provider| %>

<label class="btn btn-default">
  <%=  radio_button_tag :order, time_for_order_00_00.to_datetime, 'false',
  {:provider_id => provider.id} %><%= time_tag(time_00_00, :format => '%I:%M %p') %>
</label>

  <% end %>
</div>

<%= submit_tag "Submit", type: 'submit', :name => nil %>
```

At this time i'm seeing only :order params in the logs `:provider_id`

```
"order"=>"2016-03-09T00:00:00+00:00"
```

I tried to use `hidden_field` but it not working as expected it is always sending id for last provider in the list

Thank you, any help appreciated

Comment: Why do you need to set the time along with each provider? From your code, the `time_for_order_00_00` seems not to be dependent on the `provider` and thus seems to be the same for all radio buttons. If that is the case, you could simply send the time for order in a single hidden field.

Comment: send an array, and fetch using the index in the controller.  `<%=  radio_button_tag :order, [time_for_order_00_00.to_datetime,provider.id], 'false',
  {:provider_id => provider.id} %><%= time_tag(time_00_00, :format => '%I:%M %p') %>`  ,                               `controller_action => params[:order[0]]  ,params[:order[1]]  `

Comment: @Sravan Thanks for your response. I'm trying to fetch parameter in controller, but for some reason  it is empty.
[Here is my log "order"=>"2016-03-09T00:00:00+00:00 1" ] Testing like    def order_create
      if params[:order].present?
      flash[:alert] = params[:order[1]]
      redirect_to (:back)
      else
        flash[:alert] = "2"
        redirect_to (:back)
      end
    end

Comment: @Sravan I figure it out. Using split method and it helping me to use index for params. Thanks for awesome solution params[:order].split[0]

Comment: okay, no mentions dude, I am pasting it as an answer. Please accept it if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send an array from the rado button tag, and fetch using the index value in the controller.

```
<%= radio_button_tag :order, [time_for_order_00_00.to_datetime,provider.id], 'false', {:provider_id => provider.id} %><%= time_tag(time_00_00, :format => '%I:%M %p') %> , controller_action => params[:order[0]] ,params[:order[1]]
```

In the controller,

```
def you_method
  @time = params[:order].split[0]
  @provider = params[:order].split[1]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out with help of @Sravan.

```
View will looks like:
<%= radio_button_tag :order, [time_for_order_00_00.to_datetime,provider.id],
'false', {:provider_id => provider.id} %><%= time_tag(time_00_00, :format => '%I:%M %p') %>
```

and

```
Controller will be: 
@time_from = params[:order].split[0]
@provide_id = params[:order].split[1]
```